# Virtual phone line simulator

Tags: simulator, telephony, phone-call

I am going to write an IVR system, and I wonder if there is a phone line simulator.
What I mean is a software which creates some virtual devices which act like a voice modem or an Analog Telephony Card, and simulates some random or periodic calls through this virtual devices.

I have searched the net, but unfortunately I was not able to find something useful.

Does anyone know of anything?